# Unable to create docker virtual machine

Tags: docker, virtualbox, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-toolbox

I was using boot2docker previously and everything was working fine. Now when I upgraded to using Docker Toolbox, I am unable to create a new virtual machine.

I am even unable to import the virtual machine that was used with boot2docker.

I get this error when trying to create a new machine:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\kitematic\resources\resources\docker-machine.exe -D create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default returned non zero exit code. Stderr: Converting from raw image file="stdin" to file="C:\Users\disk.vmdk"... Creating dynamic image with size 20971520000 bytes (20000MB)... Error creating machine: exit status 1 You will want to check the provider to make sure the machine and associated resources were properly removed.
```

And I get this when trying to import the old vm that boot2docker used:'

```
C:\Users\pmandayam>docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-import-boot2 
docker-vm boot2docker-vm docker-vm 
Creating VirtualBox VM... 
Error creating machine: exit status 1 
You will want to check the provider to make sure the machine and associated reso 
urces were properly removed.
```

Assistance, is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Prithvi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by reinstalling the Docker Toolbox, make sure you install all the components of the Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Comment: I encountered similar issues on Mac OSX 10.11, and fixed it by reinstalling the Docker Toolbox as well. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed kernel driver.
You can run this:

> yum -y install kmod-VirtualBox-$(uname -r) kmod-VirtualBox

or

> yum -y install akmod-VirtualBox kernel-devel-$(uname -r) akmods
>
> systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service

and you should make sure that your firewall have been stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest test build of Virtual Box solved the problem for me!

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is actually

`docker-machine rm DOCKERHOST`

where `DOCKERHOST` is the machine name (e.g. `boot2docker-vm` in the original post above).